# Android SDK issues?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

I imported my project recently. I face the issue that is sometime It can not reference Android Java class.

[image]

and more ..

[image]

But when I open the Android SDK code. The missing class is available. Does anyone know why it says "Cannot resolve symbol"

I also tried to invalidate Android Studio Caches and Restart but it still has the issues.

Gradle build errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does a gradle build from a terminal work?

Comment: @Bajal No, build by Android Studio .

Comment: please post your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Check which android sdk you are compiling for compatibility with. Though you may be targetting 21, if you are requesting compatibility with an older version it will not let you use new classes. If that is the case, up the minSdkVersion setting in your gradle file, such as to

minSdkVersion 21